# Was Orys Baratheon the first Hand of the King?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

After Aegon's Landing, Orys Baratheon was made his Hand, making him the first Hand of the King to the Targaryen dynasty. What I want to know is if this is where the practice started. It's entrenched enough that almost all the claimants to the Iron Throne name Hands after declaring themselves King/Queen - Renly, Stannis, Dany and

> Aegon VI

all do it. Did the petty Kings of Westeros do this before Aegon's Landing or did Aegon I start the tradition?

Comment: Robb didn't appoint a Hand. And neither did Balon or Euron Greyjoy. That might indicate it being a tradition coming from Valyria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Orys Baratheon was indeed the first to hold the position known as Hand of the King. Aegon I basically created the post when he first assigned it to Orys shortly after landing in the mainland of Westeros, using the following words to describe Orys:

> "My shield, my stalwart, my strong right hand"

And from that came the position's name.

Source: [A George R R Martin reading from Chicon 7](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Chicon_7_Reading)